# How does Ruby's replace work?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking at ruby's replace: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001144

It doesn't seem to make sense to me, you call replace and it replaces the entire string.

I was expecting:

```
replace(old_value, new_value)
```

Is what I am looking for gsub then?

replace seems to be different than in most other languages.

Comment: I've marked this -1 because you've already got the answer, you already know where the API docs are and, apparently, you even know how to read them. So what's the question? It's not what the title says, "How does Ruby's replace work?" The question might be "do I really need a regex for a simple replace?" or something... not sure.

Comment: +1 just because I don't think it deserved a downvote. it's not an unclear question, it's not spam, it's not off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that [replace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28string_functions%29#replace) is generally used as some sort of pattern replace in other languages, but Ruby is different :)

Yes, you are thinking of gsub:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > "Hello World!".gsub("World", "Earth")
 => "Hello Earth!"
```

One thing to note is that String#replace may seem pointeless, however it does remove 'taintediness". You can read more up on tained objects [here.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the reason you feel that `replace` does not make sense is because there is assigment operator `=` (not much relevant to `gsub`).

The important point is that `String` instances are mutable objects. By using `replace`, you can change the content of the string while retaining its identity as an object. Compare:

```
a = 'Hello' # => 'Hello'
a.object_id # => 84793190

a.replace('World') # => 'World'
a.object_id # => 84793190

a = 'World' # => 'World'
a.object_id # => 84768100
```

See that `replace` has not changed the string object's id, whereas simple assignment did change it. This difference has some consequences. For example, suppose you assigned some instance variables to the string instance. By `replace`, that information will be retained, but if you assign the same variable simply to a different string, all that information is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is `gsub` and it is taken from **awk** syntax. I guess `replace` stands for the internal representation of the string, since, according to documentation, tainted-ness is removed too.